# Yii2 Kartik Select2 Multiple Tags Input String Error

Tags: mysql, yii2, widget, jquery-select2

I used Select2 widget to store selected tags input to MySQL database. I'am expecting something like `010102, 010103, 010299` to be stored in the database table.

Here is the **view.php**

```
    echo $form->field($model, 'SpField')->label(false)->widget(Select2::className(), [
        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Supplierfield::find()->all(), 'sfCode', 'sfCode'),
        'options' => [
            'multiple' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'Choose tag ...',
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'tags' => true
        ]
    ]);
```

UPDATED : Here is the corresponding rules on the model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['spCode', 'SpName','SpPhone', 'SpEmail', 'SpAddress', 'SpPostcode', 'SpTown', 'SpState', 'SpDistrict','SpBumi', 'SpStatus'], 'required'],
        [['RecordStamp','SpField'], 'safe'],
        [['spCode'], 'string', 'max' => 7],
        [['SpName', 'SpEmail'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['SpPhone'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['SpAddress'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['SpPostcode'], 'string', 'max' => 5],
        [['SpTown', 'SpState'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
        [['SpBumi', 'SpStatus'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
        [['SpDistrict'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['spbalance','spfloatbalance'], 'number'],
        [['SpField'], 'string', 'max' => 255, 'message' => 'Field must be a string'],
        [['spCode'], 'unique'],
    ];
}
```

but, why am I getting this error. It says that the input field must be a string.

[image]

FYI : `SpField` is varchar(255)'s field and `sfCode` is varchar(10)'s field.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: multiple Select2 post a array, you have to make it a string before you validate data. please show your model rule

Comment: @HasiburRahaman I have updated the question. How do I convert it to string?

Comment: 1 You can remove this rule       [['SpField'], 'string', 'max' => 255, 'message' => 'Field must be a string'],
2 ) Make this array to string using json_encode($model->SpField)  before validate it,

Comment: @HasiburRahaman I did what you suggest. Thanks, now I'm be able to save something like `["010101","010104","010299","010399","010501"]` in the table using json_encode. But, is that the way I should save the tags data in the database? Because I'm gonna shows it back in a view.

Comment: yes you can do it , When you want to display, use `json_decode` funtion to get array again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've done as suggested by @HasiburRahman.

**1**. Eliminate the string validation rule in model **`Supplier`** because the widget input is in array form and not string.

```
[['SpField'], 'string', 'max' => 255, 'message' => 'Field must be a string'],
```

**2**. Convert the input into string using `json_encode()` and save it in the controller.

```
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) 
    {
        $model->SpField = json_encode(Yii::$app->request->post( 'Supplier' )['SpField']); //convert the array into string
        $model->save();            
    }
```

> You may use **`json_decode()`** to convert it back to array to display `$data` using the **Select2** widget. In my case
>   it look something like this `$data = json_decode($model->SpField);`

For a newbie like me, this work very well. Hope this will help others too.

Answer (score 1):

implode the input with coma value and blankspace

> ", "

for query to the db.

```
public function actionCreateOrUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->SpField = implode (", ",$model->SpField);
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create_or_update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```